# Why is the code not able to scrape any content in the HTML class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I can see during `inspect` that the content lies in the class `article-wrap`, as highlighted in the screenshot:

[image]

But when I try to scrape the text content in it, I get nothing:

[image]

Why is that? Am I specifying the class wrongly? If so, which class do I need to specify? What's the simplest way to know which class (or tag, or div, etc) I should specify?

This is the code:

```
import requests

links = open("article links.txt", "r")

for a in links:
    page = requests.get(a)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    html = soup.find(class_="article-wrap")

    print(html)
```

Comment: I tested your code and it's working. Could you print out the links in the loop to actually check if the link is valid and pointing to a page with an actual `article-wrap` div ? I've just used a single link to an article.

Comment: can you give a url for example?

Comment: @Elad try [this](http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News/View-NewsLetter-Article/id/42946/Type/eDaily/India-M-A-deals-brewing-in-insurance-sector), that is what i found after squinting my eyes at the website in the picture..

Comment: @Cicero I checked the first 5 links in `article links.txt`; they do have the text content in the `article-wrap` class.

Comment: @Kristada673 alright, then i am at a loss. But just to make sure, print out the contents of the file in the actual python script, to make sure it's reading the file and lines correctly.

Comment: @Elad You can try http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/Magazine/ReadMagazineArticle/aid/40847/Creating-a-growth-environment-for-health-insurance-in-Asia

Comment: @Kristada673 btw, have you imported BeautifulSoup? Your example doesn't show, but i added it myself - thinking you had it omitted for some reason. So if you dont have it, add `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in the top.

Comment: @Kristada673 in the example you gave me the class is: "mag-article-wrap"

Comment: @Cicero Yeah, I imported BeautifulSoup in a previous cell. I imported in this cell and tried running the code, same result.

Comment: @Elad Oh??!!! That's strange, coz for me it says `<div class="article-wrap">` for all the articles (I checked for the first 5 links in the text doc manually).

Comment: @Kristada673, I can not recreate your issue, I get different results :( . maybe you can try this? html = soup.find(class_=['mag-article-wrap', 'article-wrap'])

Comment: @Cicero I am not able to open the links with code. But I can open them when I copy paste it onto the browser manually. So, I think the site is blocking the opening of web pages from my code, not sure. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @Kristada673 I think that @Elad is onto something. The pages may vary. Meaning one might have `<div class="article-wrap">` and another might have `<div class="mag-article-wrap">` so you should try and check both.

Comment: @Cicero Actually, it turned out to be 2 things: (1) in `article links.txt`, each link was ended with a `\n`. So, I had to `a=a.rstrip()` before `page = requests.get(a)`. So stupid. And (2), yes, I added both html classes to accommodate for the 2 different kinds of articles. Now it works fine :)

Comment: @Kristada673 super, consider writing up the answer yourself and accepting it :)

Comment: @Kristada673, glad to hear it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use BeautifulSoup's `.select()` method, similar to css selectors, such as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36'}

links = open("article links.txt", "r")

for a in links:
    r = requests.get(a, headers=headers, timeout=10)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    results = soup.select(".article-wrap"):

    print(results)
```

I tested on my computer. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned out to be 2 things:

Firstly, in `article links.txt`, each link was in a new line (i.e., ended with a `\n`). So, I had to do `a=a.rstrip()` before `page = requests.get(a)` to get the correct soup. Without the strip, if I print out the soup, it looks like this:

```
>>> page = requests.get('http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law\n')
>>> page
<Response [400]>
>>> page.text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

As can be seen, without stripping the `\n` at the end of each link, it can't extract the info in the page (in particular, there's no tag `artcle-wrap` in the soup it extracts).

Secondly, I added both html classes, `article-wrap` and `mag-article-wrap` to accommodate for the 2 different kinds of articles:

```
html = soup.find(class_='article-wrap')
if html==None:
    html = soup.find(class_='mag-article-wrap')

text = get_text(html.text)
```

Now it works fine.